# How to have a region inside a Drupal form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, theming

I am trying to modify drupal comment form so that just above the the form I can show a regions and add more blocks to that region (say some promotional banners).

I am doing this in template.php
I have a working themename_comment_form function and can set `$form['intro']['#value']` to the value I want.  I also know how to create a  new region.

What I am struggling is to get the value of that region (say `$above_comment_form`) and make it available inside themename_comment_form (something like `$form['intro']['#value'] = $above_comment_form;`)
I have tried preprocess_page, preprocess_node to set the value like `$vars['above_comment_form']=$above_comment_form` but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

To create a region, you need to add it in your module's `.info` file. If you don't have any regions defined, the default is to have 5 available:

- left
- right
- content
- header
- footer

If you want to add/remove regions you will need to write **all** the regions you want in your theme. So to include the custom region you would need to have this in your `.info` file:

```
regions[header] = "Header"
regions[left] = "Left sidebar"
regions[content] = "Content"
regions[right] = "Right sidebar"
regions[footer] = "Footer"
regions[above_comment_form] = "Above the comment form"
```

Now regions are only available in your `page.tpl.php` by default. You can get the blocks in a region that's available to the user by using `theme_blocks`. So in your `preprocess_node`function you would need to add:

```
$vars['above_comment_form'] = theme('blocks', 'above_comment_form');
```

Then in your node.tpl.php you can do this:

```
<div id="above_comment_form">
  <?php print $above_comment_form; ?>
</div>
```

That should accomplish your task.

Answer (score 1):

The rendering of regions happens very late in the call stack so most times it is not possible to include them in something like a theme function or a form_alter.

However you can render individual blocks in those, so if you are looking to add a specific block using something like:

```
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', 26);
print $block['content'];
```

Which will work in theme functions and templates. I tried doing something simular and dug pretty deep in the page rendering to look for the functions that rendered the regions, and it was either not possible, or not worth it to try to render the region earlier in the stack.